# Bootstrap 3 Grid: Overflowing columns behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using this layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <!-- and on and on -->
</div>
```

The content in each column is variable in size, this causes a strange flow in the browser. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hImcS.gif).

As you can see, columns 4,5,6 are in a new "row". and columns 7 and 8 have skipped a whole column. These behaviors are not desireable, Instead I want the columns to flow like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daWdj.gif).

In this situation every column hugs the column it's under. I haven't found a fix yet for this problem. I have looked into `clearfix`. and it does not seem to help the situation, as it just moves a column to a newline/row.

Comment: [you should read the documentation on the BS grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/). basically each row should have a total of 12 column width. You are just adding cells by values of 4 so in your code above you have 4 x 8 which is 32 cells across and its overflowing on your page.

Comment: yes i know it's incorrect to have more than 12 columns in a row, but for the desired situation adding in rows would not be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is often reffered as a Pinterest style grid.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 470px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* Shorthand – you could use ‘flex-direction: column’ and ‘flex-wrap: wrap’ instead */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 150px;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 250px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 190px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 220px;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/michellebarker/pen/zvxpoG

Or this alternative: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/pinterest-like-responsive-grid. Or [search for more examples](https://www.google.nl/search?q=bootstrap%20pinterest%20grid&oq=bootstrap%20pinter&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5672j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Exactly what i needed, totally forgot that pinterest used this layout too.